# If $a \in G$, and $ab \in G$, can we have that $b \in G$ as well?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $a \in G$, and $ab \in G$, can we have that $b \in G$ as well?

I am trying to prove another question, which I am going to use "if $a \in G$ and $ab \in G$, then $b \in G$". But I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: If $a \in G$ what can you say about $a^{-1}$?

Comment: If $b \notin G$, what does $ab$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is a group, then yes. If $a\in G$, then $a^{-1}\in G$. Since $a^{-1}\in G$ and $ab\in G$ we also have $a^{-1}ab = eb=b\in G$.

Comment: I was stuck here for a while..Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious that when $G$ is a group then for all $a,b\in G$, we have $ab\in G$. In fact, $G$ is closed under its own operation so what is mean if $b$ is not in $G$. I mean @Michael's neat comment again.

Comment: @amWhy: Hope you are feeling better! Regards

Comment: Hi, @Babak!! +1